# how to compute log factorial of an array of numbers

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

The quantity to be computed is `log(k!)`, where `k` could be 4000 or even higher, but of course the log will compensate. I tried computing `sum(log(k))` which is the same.

So, I am given an large array with integers and I want to efficiently compute `sum(log(k))`. This was my attempt:

```
integers = np.asarray([435, 535, 242,])

score = np.sum(np.log(np.arange(1,integers+1)))
```

This would work, except that `np.arange` would generate an array of different size for each integer, so when I run that, it gives me an error (as it should).

The problem could be easily solved with a `for` loop as follows:

```
scores = []
for i in range(integers.shape[0]):
    score = np.sum(np.log(np.arange(1,integer[i]+1)))
    scores.append(score)
```

but that's too slow. My actual `integers` has millions of value to be computed.

Is there an efficient implementation for this that basically that doesn't need a for loop? I was thinking of a `lambda` function or something like that, but I am not really sure how to apply it. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can vectorize with something like this:

```
mi = integers.max()
ls = np.log(np.arange(2, mi + 1))
```

Two optimizations so far: you only need the range up to the maximum, since the other numbers are covered by that, and you don't need `log(1)`.

Now you take the cumulative sum:

```
cs = np.cumsum(ls)
```

The desired elements can be indexed directly:

```
result = cs[integers - 2]
```

If this is something you need to do many times, and you know the upper bound, this solution will be much faster than using `math.lgmamma` or `scipy.special.gammaln` once you precompute `cs` to the upper bound.

If this is a one-time call, here is the obligatory one-liner:

```
np.cumsum(np.log(np.arange(2, np.max(integers))))[integers - 2]
```

You can do most of the operations in-place if memory is a concern (I think it also makes them faster):

```
mi = integers.max()
cs = np.arange(2, mi + 1)
np.cumsum(np.log(cs, out=cs), out=cs)
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution!

Comment: Glad you like it :)

Answer (score 6):

How about math.lgamma? Gamma function is factorial, and [`lgamma`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.lgamma) is log of gamma.

You don't need to compute factorial and then log.

There is also [`gammaln`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.gammaln.html) in the SciPy

Code, Python 3.9 x64 Win 10

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import gammaln

startf = 1 # start of factorial sequence
stopf  = 400 # end of of factorial sequence

q = gammaln(range(startf+1, stopf+1)) # n! = G(n+1)
print(q)
```

looks reasonable to me

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @Schach21 updated the answer with sample code from SciPy, might be faster due to vectorization

Comment: Why are you summing?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Ah, got it, my mistake. Post corrected, thank you

Comment: @Schach21 Note that `lgamma`  is generally more stable numerically than computing `log(n!)` manually (ie. more accurate).